# How can I make three.js update a scene after adding an object or group of objects?

Tags: three.js

I am fairly new to three.js and have a problem I can't readily find an answer for.

Here is a codepen that should sum up the situation: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPYPzO

```
var container, stats;
var camera, controls, scene, renderer, raycaster, mouse;

init();
animate();
add_world();

var indie_render = true;
for(var j = 0; j < 20; j++){
  add_objects(20);
  indie_render = !indie_render;
  console.log("adding more objects...");
  if(!indie_render){render();}
}


function add_world(){
  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1000, 1000, 1000);
  var mesh = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xf5f5dc, wireframe: false, opacity: 0.2, transparent:true } );
  var world = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mesh );
  scene.add( world );
  render();
}

function add_objects(num, indiv){
  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 32,32 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { shading: THREE.FlatShading } );
  material.color.setRGB( Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random() );
  for ( var i = 0; i < num; i ++ ) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.x = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 1000;
    mesh.position.y = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 1000;
    mesh.position.z = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 1000;
    mesh.updateMatrix();
    mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    scene.add( mesh );
    if(indie_render){
      console.log("individual render");
      render();
    }
  }
}

function init() {
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
  camera.position.set(500, 500, -1000);
    camera.up.set( 0, 1, 0 );
    camera.lookAt(500,500,500);
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
  controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

  //world
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // lights
  light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
  light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
  scene.add( light );

  light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
  light.position.set( -1, -1, -1 );
  scene.add( light );

  light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
  scene.add( light );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
  renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 1 );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  renderer.sortObjects = false;
  container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
  container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
  raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  container.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
  container.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onMouseDown, false );
  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  controls.update();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}


function onMouseMove( e ) {
  mouse.x = ( e.clientX / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( e.clientY / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;
}

function onMouseDown( e ) {
  mouse.x = ( e.clientX / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( e.clientY / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;

  if(e.button == 2){    //right button
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
      var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 32,32 );
      var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:0xff0000, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      mesh.position.set(intersects[0].point.x, intersects[0].point.y, intersects[0].point.z);
      scene.add(mesh);
      render();
    }
  }
}
```

In this demo, I init() and animate() a blank scene, and then add a translucent cube, following what seems to be convention. Then I add groups of spheres to the scene in a nested for loop, randomly placing the spheres inside the cube and making a render() call after every scene.add() call.

Currently, the scene adds all the spheres and only then is visible to the user, even though I can add individual objects after the for-loop objects are added (by right-clicking on the cube). I need for the user to be able to watch as spheres are added, rather than waiting for the whole thing to be done.

I realize this may not be the most efficient way to render the scene, but it would be quite helpful if, for example, the info on the objects to be animated is arriving asynchronously from a server. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) First: move call `render()` to `animate`:

```
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  render();
  controls.update();
}
```

2) Call `add_objects` asynchronously: `setTimeout( add_objects, 0, 20 );`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVbEEP

Comment: Thank you! I had tried a setTimeout() call before but didn't have render() in the right place then. Works great.